# Flutter - Change Switch Border Color?

Tags: flutter

Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html

How do I change the border Color when the Switch is turned off? In Material 3, when it is on, the border color is the same as the Switch background color, but when it is off, it has a border. How do I change it in Material 3?

[image]

Code:

```
Switch(
                      trackColor: (miniVerbose)
                          ? const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.greenAccent)
                          : const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.orange),
                      value: miniVerbose,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          miniVerbose = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: If you add the field borderColor the same as you did with trackColor, is it still not working?

See guide:
https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-guide-flutter-switches-toggles

Comment: @RimonFedyuk borderColor is not a property, at least not with the new Flutter.

Answer (score 3):

flutter 3.10 add [trackOutlineColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchThemeData/trackOutlineColor.html) for Switch

```
trackOutlineColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
  (final Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
      return null;
    }

    return AppColors.slateGray;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ).copyWith(
        colorScheme:
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(outline: Colors.orange),
      ),
```

Switch:

```
Switch(
       value: value,
       activeTrackColor: Colors.orange,
       inactiveTrackColor: Colors.yellow,
       activeColor: Colors.yellow,
       onChanged: (_) => setState(() => value = !value),
     ),
```

[image]

Comment: This is great globally, but how do I change it just for one Switch?

Answer (score 1):

just updated Vivek code and wrap switch with Theme widget for single button, below is updated code-

```
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ).copyWith(
        colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(outline: Colors.orange),
      ),
      child: Switch(
        value: value,
        activeTrackColor: Colors.orange,
        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.yellow,
        activeColor: Colors.yellow,
        onChanged: (_) => setState(() => value = !value),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Yes, this is better way to change the border color for individual Switches.

Answer (score 0):

```
what about this alternative: 

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    border: Border.all(
      color: isSwitchedOn ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey,
      width: 2.0,
    ),
  ),
  child: Switch(
    value: isSwitchedOn,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        isSwitchedOn = value;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```